# Как найти элемент и все последующие элементы после него?

Tags: java, android, exchange

Использую java ews api. У меня есть сообщение.Хочу обратиться к серверу с этим сообщением и получить все последние сообщения которые идут после моего.Как такое реализовать?Как найти поинт на мое сообщение?

Answer (score 0):

Каждый пользователь подключается к этому серверу и посылает ему свои сообщения. Сервер хранит список подключенных пользователей и рассылает им все полученные сообщения.  данные передаются через Socketсодержит входной и выходной потоки класса InputStreamи OutputStream.нужно сначала передать имя пользователя а затем каждое введённое (в консоль) сообщение отправлять серверу.